# Combine inner arrays in a multi-dimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array:

```
array(
   array( 
    'Friend',
    'Amigo',
    '',
    ''
   ),

   array( 
    'Friend',
    '',
    'Fraund',
    ''
   ),

   array(
    'Thanks',
    'Gracias',
    '',
    ''
   ),

   array(
    'Thanks',
    '',
    'Danke',
    ''
   )
);
```

Basically, I need to combine inner arrays when they have the same values in a corresponding order. For example, 'friend' and 'thanks' in a current example. Output should be:

```
array(
   array( 
    'Friend',
    'Amigo',
    'Fraund',
    ''
   ),

   array(
    'Thanks',
    'Gracias',
    'Danke',
    ''
   )
);
```

Thus, the empty element needs to be overwritten by the corresponding element which has got some value. Cannot figure out how to do it with `array_merge`.

Comment: Does the order matter? As in, `['Friend', '', 'Amigo', 'Fraund']` is okay?

Comment: @Ja͢ck, yes, it goes in a respective language order: English, Spanish, German, and, for example, Italian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) like this:

```
$result = array_values(array_reduce($a, function(array &$final, $current) {
    $key = $current[0];

    if (isset($final[$key])) {
        // replace items that are not an empty string
        $final[$key] = array_replace($final[$key], array_filter($current, 'strlen'));
    } else {
        $final[$key] = $current;
    }
    return $final;
}, []));
```

The reduce operation creates an array whereby the first word of each array is used as the key; `array_replace()` updates existing values with new ones if the string is not empty.

The end result is then pulled through `array_values()` to get rid of the temporary keys that were used during the reduce operation.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. Nice and simple. The only problem I get is when I loop through the array and put it into a .csv format file, it brings Unicode problems which I didn't have before. For instance, some Spanish letters, or Russian letters look awful. I know it has nothing to do with the current question, but for any help on this I would say Thanks!

Comment: @KananFarzali Yeah, that shouldn't be related to this answer; you may want to look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) to see what you may have missed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd go about it like this

```
$final_array = array();
$original_array = array(
    array( 
        'Friend',
        'Amigo',
        '',
        ''
    ),

    array( 
        'Friend',
        '',
        'Fraund',
        ''
    ),

    array(
        'Thanks',
        'Gracias',
        '',
        ''
    ),

    array(
        'Thanks',
        '',
        'Danke',
        ''
        )
    );
 $friends_array = array();
 foreach($original_array[0] as $row) {
     if($row != "") {
         array_push($friends_array, $row);
     }
 }
 foreach($original_array[1] as $row) {
     if($row != "" && !in_array($row, $friends_array)) {
         array_push($friends_array, $row);
     }
 }
 $thanks_array = array();
 foreach($original_array[2] as $row) {
     if($row != "") {
         array_push($thanks_array, $row);
     }
 }
 foreach($original_array[3] as $row) {
     if($row != "" && !in_array($row, $thanks_array)) {
         array_push($thanks_array, $row);
     }
 }
 array_push($final_array, $friends_array, $thanks_array);
```

You do have a very specific request. Rather odd tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the array, add the values to a new array (indexed by the 1st element in the internal arrays), then use `array_values` to get your desired output (or leave it indexed as is, which may be beneficial for further data access):

```
$out = [];
foreach ($input as $val) {
    $key = $val[0]; 
    foreach ($val as $item) {
        if(!empty($item) && $item !=$key){
            $out[$key][]=$item;
        }
    }
    if(!in_array($key, $out[$key])) $out[$key][]=$key;
}
$out = array_values($out);
var_dump($out);
```

Live working example:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/EoRhh2

Comment: Thanks Steve. It does half of the job. But your output is not the same I expect. Firstly, it removes the last empty elements of all inner arrays which should stay. Secondly, the order is very important. It should stay in the same order as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

in php you can use

```
array_unique($arr1,$arr2);
or
array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

But in your condition you ahve a single array which you have to split into different arrays

```
$mainArary = array(
  array( 
   'Friend',
   'Amigo',
   '',
   ''
 ),
 array( 
  'Friend',
  '',
  'Fraund',
  ''
 ),
 array(
  'Thanks',
  'Gracias',
  '',
  ''
 ),
 array(
  'Thanks',
  '',
  'Danke',
  ''
 )
);
$first_array = null;
$second_array = null;
$i = 0;
foreach($mainArray[0] as $arr){
  if($i < 2){
  if($prev_array == null){
    $prev_array = $arr;
  } else {
    $prev_array = array_merge($prev_array,$arr);
  } } else {
    if($second_array == null){
    $second_array = $arr;
  } else {
    $second_array = array_merge($second_array ,$arr);
  }
 }
}
print_r($prev_array);
print_r($second_array);
```

Here is your desired output.